# QoS Policy applied via GPO does not show up in the local group policy

Tags: windows, group-policy, qos

We have setup a group policy in our domain for QoS Policies and have linked it to the proper OU. I can see that the GP is applied when running gpresult, but when I look at the Local Group Policy settings I don't see these polices listed there.

Here is the group policy in Group Policy Managment

[image]

Here is the gpresult from one of the machines in the OU this policy is linked to

[image]

And here is the Local Computer Policy on that same machine

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I can see that other policies that are applied are showing up in the Local Group Policy setting, but not this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the local group policy settings. You are not looking at the resultant set of policies applied from both AD and from the local security policy. Run rsop.msc (resultant set of policies) on the computer and look under Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates>Extra Registry Settings for your QOS settings.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I might be looking in the wrong place, but I saw other GP settings in the local group policy settings and that threw me off.